# iOS: Obtaining path of file in c code

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, file, file-io

I am having an iOS Project in which i use some C-Sources.
In the C part I need the path to a file in the mainbundle.
How can I obtain it without using Obj-C?

Basically I want to have the path returned by:

```
NSLog(@"%s",[[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"txt"] fileSystemRepresentation]);
```

Comment: Could you make a helper function that provides a C interface and converts the `NSString` to a `char*` and returns that?

Comment: Cornstalks, CFString already provides a C interface to NSString. You can freely cast between CFStringRef and NSString*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best you read the path with objective-c and pass it as char * to the c class by calling a function.
You further could asign a global variable char * which is visible for both objective-c and C.

Answer (score 2):

So just get the path as you did above, and then get a C string version:

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"txt"] fileSystemRepresentation];
char *cPath = [path cStringUsingEncoding:UTF8StringEncoding];
```

Just pay attention to the warning in the docs and copy the string if you plan to hang onto it beyond the end of the method/function that you're in:

> The returned C string is guaranteed to be valid only until either the
>   receiver is freed, or until the current autorelease pool is emptied,
>   whichever occurs first. You should copy the C string or use
>   getCString:maxLength:encoding: if it needs to store the C string
>   beyond this time.

**Update:** If for whatever reason you can't use Foundation, you can do something similar using Core Foundation. You can call `CFBundleCopyResourceURL()` (or one of its cousins) to get the URL for the resource, and then convert that to a path using `CFURLCopyPath()`.

Comment: @Jakob Post updated, though it's hard to imagine what you're doing in iOS that prevents you from using any Objective-C -- you could always use Obj-C in a different file or in a library, for example.